# Foreignkey-Relation for two tables

Tags: sql, database

I have the following two tables.

```
[Person]
Id [INTEGER] PRIMARY KEY
Firstname [VARCHAR]
Lastname [VARCHAR]
Birthday [DATETIME2]

[Address]
Id [INTEGER] PRIMARY KEY
Street [VARCHAR]
ZipCode [INTEGER]
City [VARCHAR]
Country [VARCHAR]
```

I'm not sure where to put the foreign-key.

Is it better to put a foreign key into the Person-Table or into the Address-Table?
My first idea would be to put it into the Person-Table, because this is my "main"-table

Comment: If a person only has one address, why are you putting the address in a different table? It'd be simpler to just add the address fields to the Person table.

Comment: This would not be conform with databasenormalisation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. A person has only one address or more than one ?

- If only one, I think it's more logic to put IdAddress in the Person table because one person has one address, and not, one address has one person
- If more than one, maybe you should create a join table with IdPerson and IdAddress.

Comment: A person only has one address. Ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```
[Address]
PersonId [INTEGER] (References [Person].[Id])
```

Comment: why would you do this? in RL it will be an `Person 1:n:n:1 Address` relation